# C++ pass by reference - can this be done?

Tags: c++, function, reference

I have several files which is causing a compile error, can the following be done?

header1.h

```
class Class1{
public:
void function1(Class1 &);
};
```

header2.h

```
class Class2{
public:
void function2(Class2 &, Class1 &);
};
```

cpp2.cpp

```
#include "header2.h"
void Class2::function2(Class2 & my2Class, Class1 & my1Class){};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"

// functions
```

The error is stating that header2.h knows nothing of Class1 as a type. How can I declare an object of type Class1 in this header file, without using an include or without putting both classes in the same file (they are entirely separate and should only meet inside functions called within main)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use forward declarations:

```
class Class1; //forward declare Class1
class Class2{
public:
void function2(Class2 &, Class1 &);
};
```

Passing a parameter of a type to a function doesn't require the type to be fully defined.

Comment: This seams to work best in my particular application. I have also had to include header1.h in my cpp2.cpp file. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @ChrisJones :))) you're getting a bit to formal. I just thought you made a mistake (not a typo) and wanted to warn you before you logged off SO and sent that code into production. :P

Answer (score 0):

let every header include each other header that it requires information about, but with a preprocessing definition to avoid circular references or repeated declarations. e.g.
header2 should be

```
#ifndef FUNCS_H

#define FUNCS_H

#include "header1.h"

    class Class2{
    public:
    void function2(Class2 &, Class1 &);
    };
#endif
```

This is how I do all my headers in C++

Comment: While it's true that you should add preprocessor guards.  This won't help avoid circular references.

Comment: You should also prefer forward declarations instead of includes.

Comment: Why are forward declerations better?  I would have thought that simply including other headers has the same end effect, and saves you the trouble of explicitely forward-declaring something every time you realize you need it.